# How to solve: Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it’s too old -- using global CLI?

Tags: ionic-framework

`ionic -v` results in this warning:

> [WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it’s too old -- using global CLI.

How to uninstall local Ionic CLI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ionic-cli** has been updated to version 4.0.1 a couple of days ago.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md

You should remove local cli by `npm remove ionic --save-dev` and use global one instead.

`npm i -g ionic`

PS: For ionic v1 project, you have to install `@ionic/v1-toolkit` now.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/v1-toolkit

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on my app as well.
I no longer had '@ionic/cli' or 'ionic' as a dependency, but every time I re-ran "npm i" it would return as a locally installed item.  Looking through my package-lock.json I saw that it was also being installed as a dependency of @types/ionic which I then removed and solved this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove old ionic:

```
npm remove ionic
```

And then install ionic v 4.0.1:

```
npm install ionic@latest --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove local Ionic CLI npm package:

```
npm rm ionic --save
```